# What really is the different between setting a wpf control content property Implicitly vs explicitly

Tags: wpf, xaml

This is setting the `Content` properly explicitly

```
<Button x:Name ="myButton" Height ="50" Width ="100" Content = "OK">
</Button>
```

This is implicitly.

```
<Button x:Name ="myButton" Height ="50" Width ="100">
"OK"
</Button>
```

I guess this is implicitly because we are not really mentioning `Content`by name but how does `OK` get assigned to `Content` anyways because a button has many others properties? Why it does't assign to any other property?

While googling, I see implicit/explicit with styles which makes sense but how are they really implicit/explicit in this case? What is the advantage of one over the other if any in this case or difference?

Answer (score 1):

each WPF control has a defined property that gets set when you use it implicitly. In `Button`'s case, it's the `Content` property. For `StackPanel` it's the `Children` property. Usually it's the one property that makes the most sense to be used implicitly.
That's it...

Comment: Also, content can be more than a simple text string. In this case, you cannot use the attribute, you have to use XML elements to represent complex content.

Comment: @DmitryArestov yes! Thanks for adding to my simplistic answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ...but how does OK get assigned to `Content` anyways because a button has many others properties?

The `ContentControl` class which `Button` is derived from (through `ButtonBase`) is decorated with the [`System.Windows.Markup.ContentPropertyAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute?view=netframework-4.8):

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
[DefaultProperty("Content")]
public class ContentControl : Control, IAddChild
...
```

This attribute indicates which property of a type that is the XAML content property and the XAML processor uses this information to set the property when processing the XAML markup.

Comment: @zar: Does this answer your question or what are you looking for?